# card ui with different card screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built a UI card with a share button. Upon tapping the share button, a share sheet shows up above the card itself.

This card will live in a grid of other such cards so the "share" button should trigger only the share sheet for the current card

I have a Save button which should also fire another sheet, but it doesnt seem to be working.

I've built this demo (http://jsfiddle.net/8hed8yrd/11/) with the share sheet working. I cant seem to get a save sheet to work. Any pointers?

Note: Demo doesn't have save sheet to avoid confusion in code.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div id="card">
        <div class="hero_text hero_small">TITLE</div>
        <div class="subtext">SUBTITLES</div>
        <div class="toggleLink explore_text"><span class="icons">SHARE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleLink explore_text"><span class="icons">SAVE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="share_sheet">
            <div class="share_this">SHARE THIS IMAGE</div>
            <div class="share_close">CLOSE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", ".toggleLink", function () {
    jQuery(this).next('.share_sheet').fadeIn('fast');
    return false;
});

jQuery(document).on("click", ".share_sheet", function () {
    jQuery(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question. The restriction on fiddle links without code is for a reason, please don't try and get around it by using URL shorteners.

Comment: So, by clicking on SHARE you want a share sheet to appear in the main `div`? By quickly glancing at your JsFiddle, I think that functionality lies within clicking on SAVE. Your description does not match what your demo actually do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use jQuery(this).next('.share_sheet'). The second toggleLink SAVE have a share_sheet div right after itself, but the SHARE button doesn't. Thats why jquery can't found the div. Use siblings instead of next if you want to found the same element, or do it like i do in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PSYKLON/8hed8yrd/12

```
    <div class="toggleLink explore_text"><span class="icons">SHARE</span></div>

    <div class="share_sheet">
    <div class = "share_this">SHARE THIS IMAGE</div>
    <div class = "share_close">CLOSE</div>
    </div>

<div class="toggleLink explore_text"><span class="icons">SAVE</span></div>


    <div class="share_sheet">
    <div class = "share_this">SAVE THIS IMAGE</div>
    <div class = "share_close">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
```